# bitwise operators not clear as to what's going on

Tags: javascript, xor

I saw this solution but don't understand how it works:

```js
const data = [17, 17, 3, 17, 17, 17, 17];
const stray = nums => nums.reduce((a, b) => a ^ b);

const res = stray(data);
console.log(res);
```

could someone explain what's happening with the reduce statement?

Comment: It's just `..((17 ^ 17) ^ 3) ^ 17...`

Comment: "I saw this solution" Solution to what?

Comment: xor has a property that `a^0 == a` and `a^a == 0`, so duplicate elements in array are turned into 0 during this process, thus returning xor between unique elements in array, if there is only one unique element - this one is returned

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Answer (score 0):

If you need to understand what `stray()` method is doing, it basically performs the **XOR** operation of elements on the array that can't be paired with a duplicated. For details, you can read one of the commentaries on your question:

> **XOR** has a property that `a ^ 0 == a` and `a ^ a == 0`, so duplicate elements in array are turned into 0 during this process.

And from this reference:

https://rohan-paul.github.io/javascript/2017/01/28/Bitwise_XOR_Operators_in_JavaScript/

It can be used to solve next problem: *Given an array, find the int that appears an odd number of times. There will always be only one integer that appears an odd number of times.*

**TEST CASES:**

```js
const data1 = [17, 17, 3, 10, 10, 3, 3];
const data2 = [1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4];
const data3 = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2];

const stray = nums => nums.reduce((a, b) => a ^ b);

console.log(stray(data1));
console.log(stray(data2));
console.log(stray(data3));
```